# We don't need this [extra] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The tag wiki excerpt for [extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extra) (136 questions) says this:

> Terminal emulation for mainframes. IBM System z (Mainframe), IBM System i (AS/400), UNIX/Linux/OpenVMS (VT), and HP NonStop/Tandem systems.

Now, the last ten questions in that tag:

- [How do I make a function that can calculate something simple if it has an extra argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514142/how-do-i-make-a-function-that-can-calculate-something-simple-if-it-has-an-extra)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467573/what-coad-extra-data
- [Mysql performance: extra field or many joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812211/mysql-performance-extra-field-or-many-joins)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629883/php-markdown-not-working-properly
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497818/extra-space-between-paragraphs-on-gmail-app
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998396/how-to-extract-the-abstract-of-an-arxiv-page
- [Start hangouts call from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878153/start-hangouts-call-from-my-app)
- [How can I scrape the correct number of URLs from an infinite-scroll webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921329/scraping-url-from-web-page)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800119/joomla-k2-how-to-order-items-by-extra-field
- [Extra quotes in ServiceStack POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678374/extra-quotes-in-servicestack-post)

And I don't see *any* questions about mainframe terminal emulation in a very quick overview of the first few pages. The tag also provides *zero* extra information for use in filtering - when would I want to search for [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)[extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extra)? I would get a smattering of... random PHP questions.

I would propose that we:

- Remove the tag from the questions that don't need it, which would seem to be a decent majority of them
- Rename the tag to something like [extra-terminal-emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extra-terminal-emulation) or something similar.
- Possibly blacklist [extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extra), because it's only a matter of time until someone with 1.5k creates it again.

Thoughts?

Comment: Blacklisting won't happen, unless you demonstrate recidivism. Aside from that, sure, go ahead.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yep, that's why I said 'possibly'. I suspect we'll have recidivism, but we can afford to wait and see.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: The punniness of the title needs work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pekka웃 [tag:extra] [tag:extra] read all about it - useless tag identified!